# Andengene get the closest sprite from a touchpoint

Tags: android, andengine

This is how I am adding the sprites randomly on screen and moving them by another function that too randomly. 
  Now my question is how can I find the closest sprite(sperm in my case) from the touch-point when User touches the screen. I have scene touchevent, I can find the distance between two sprites too but not getting how can I compare them all as I dont have instance of them as a list or like that...

Please help me

```
@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    this.mScene = new Scene();
    this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(Color.BLUE));
    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    createHandlerToAddSperms();
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    return this.mScene;
}


private void createHandlerToAddSperms() {
    // -------------------------------------------------
    mTimerClass = new TimerClass(0.7f, new TimerClass.ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTick() {

            if (!isGameOver) {
                SpermSprite sperm;
                if (mRandom == null) {
                    mRandom = new Random();
                }
                switch (mRandom.nextInt(DOWN + 1)) {
                case MainActivity.LEFT:
                    sperm = addNewSpermToScreen(0, mRandom.nextInt(CAMERA_HEIGHT), true);
                    // sperm.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                    break;
                case MainActivity.RIGHT:
                    sperm = addNewSpermToScreen(CAMERA_WIDTH, mRandom.nextInt(CAMERA_HEIGHT), true);
                    // sperm.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                    break;

                case MainActivity.UP:
                    sperm = addNewSpermToScreen(mRandom.nextInt(CAMERA_WIDTH), 0, true);
                    // sperm.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                    break;
                case MainActivity.DOWN:
                    sperm = addNewSpermToScreen(mRandom.nextInt(CAMERA_WIDTH), CAMERA_HEIGHT, true);
                    // sperm.setColor(Color.CYAN);

                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("DEFAULT case==============================");
                    break;

                }

            } else {

                mScene.unregisterUpdateHandler(mTimerClass);
                System.out.println("UNREGISTER pTimerHandler =========================");

            }

        }
    });
    // -------------------------------------------------

    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(mTimerClass);

}

private SpermSprite addNewSpermToScreen(final float pX, final float pY, final boolean modifyPath) {
    this.spermCount++;
    Debug.d("spermCount: " + this.spermCount);

    final SpermSprite sperm;
    sperm = new SpermSprite(pX, pY, this.spermTextureRegion, mBufferObjectManager) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            // addWaterDropBlast(this.getX(), this.getY(), this);
            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };

    if (modifyPath) {
        addPathModifireToDrp(sperm);
    }

    this.mScene.attachChild(sperm);
    this.mScene.registerTouchArea(sperm);
    rotateSpirmTowardsCentre(sperm);

    return sperm;

}


@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    final float touchX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
    final float touchY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

    switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------
        break;

    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        break;
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;

    }

    return true;
};
```

Comment: Hoping my post may help you to implement the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not having any method to get all sprites of Entity.So you can do  one thing 
 Add all sprites  to a list.Then find distance between other sprites to your sprite.

int preDis;
int index;

```
for(Sprite other: listOfsprites){
 distance(otherSpritePos, yourTargetPos);

  // compare all sprites in this way 
    finally you will get the index of a sprite in the list which having min distance


}  

distance(otherSpritePos, targetPos){

       int  distance  = Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2);
          if(distance< preDis){
          preDis = distance;

            // get list index of that sprite

    }
```

You can implement  logic in this way

Comment: I know this approach I thought there will be better solution than this... Still accepting your answer thanks for t help